# Xcode Archive command fails with Ionic Capacitor and React - Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: reactjs, xcode, ionic4, capacitor

For a couple of days, without changing any details on the project, I've been receiving this error during the Xcode publishing phase.
I have also shared my code with other developers, and on their computer publishing is not a problem.

Below is the error log:

```
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/[USER_NAME]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-faqqbffxhfofrrewfezzfuhlylqt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/App.build/Release-iphoneos/App.build/Script-9592DBEFFC6D2A0C8D5DEB22.sh (in target 'App' from project 'App')
    cd /Users/[USER_NAME]/Desktop/Workspace/[APP_NAME]/ios/App
    /bin/sh -c /Users/[USER_NAME]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-faqqbffxhfofrrewfezzfuhlylqt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/App.build/Release-iphoneos/App.build/Script-9592DBEFFC6D2A0C8D5DEB22.sh

mkdir -p /Users/[USER_NAME]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-faqqbffxhfofrrewfezzfuhlylqt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/App.app/Frameworks
Symlinked...
rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --links --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "../../../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Capacitor.framework" "/Users/[USER_NAME]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-faqqbffxhfofrrewfezzfuhlylqt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/App.app/Frameworks"
building file list ... rsync: link_stat "/Users/[USER_NAME]/Desktop/Workspace/[APP_NAME]/ios/App/../../../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Capacitor.framework" failed: No such file or directory (2)
done

sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Tried to reinstall Capacitor, rebuild the pods, the entire ios folder and project.
Also uninstalled and reinstalled Xcode. I'm always stuck at the same point.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: i was facing same issue not found any solution, i formatting my mac then only work

Answer (score 18):

The answer provided by [Baryon Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75918729/13690331) worked for me. However for those who are looking for the place where this change has to be applied, you should go to the following path:

`/ios/App/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-App/Pods-App-frameworks.sh`

And then replace:

`source="$(readlink "${source}")"`

with:

`source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"`

Comment: Perfect workaround!

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11808#issuecomment-1480802886

> Workaround is to update all the generated ...-frameworks.sh files to
> add the -f flag to the call to readlink. In other words, replace
> source="$(readlink "${source}")" with source="$(readlink -f
> "${source}")"
>
> This is my first time contributing to CocoaPods though, so take it
> with a grain of salt!

Answer (score 3):

I use ionic capacitor. I was facing the same issues with MacBook M1 Pro and Xcode 14.3. I downgraded Xcode to 14.2 but it slowed down the build process.

Then I reinstalled 14.3 and replaced:

```
source="$(readlink "${source}")"
```

With:

```
source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"
```

And it works. Remember to do this only before doing the Archive.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issue, XCode 14.3 is the issue! Downgrade to 14.2 and it will work. https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=14.2

Comment: I am also facing this only since this morning. XCode 14.3 - I don't want to downgrade yet

Answer (score 0):

Since changing the generated files are hard, I wrote a post_install script that does the same workaround mentioned above by others. target name depends on your project such as "App".

In your Podfile, (ios/App/Podfile) you can add this.

```rb
post_install do |installer|
  installer.aggregate_targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'Pods-<Target Name>' # Your target name here
        frameworkPath = "Pods/Target Support Files/#{target.name}/#{target.name}-frameworks.sh"
        puts "Found #{frameworkPath}"
        text = File.read(frameworkPath)
        new_contents = text.gsub('readlink "${source}"', 'readlink -f "${source}"') # Detect and replace the line
        File.open(frameworkPath, "w") {|file| file.puts new_contents}
        puts "Updated #{target.name} framework file for xcode 14.3 cocoapods issue"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It is fixed now. Update cocoapods to 1.12.1

https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/6457

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34401426)